# What's a specific word for "several places"?

Tags: single-word-requests

> If I had money , I would visit *several places*.

What's a single word to replace *several places*?

Comment: I don't think there's a word that replaces the word *places* along with its determiner, which could be "some", "a few", "many", "five", etc. You might say *I would visit around.* , or *I would go visiting.*, which would suggest more than one place.

Comment: "Everywhere" could be used, but it is excessive (all is more than several in this context). Is there a reason you need a single word?

Comment: The adverb [extensively](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extensively) has a similar meaning, but you want a noun?

Answer (score 1):

I think "If I had money , I would travel." without specifying a destination implies travelling to multiple destinations.